# How to use GTM trigger name in custom javascript conditional statement?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm wondering whether it is possible in a custom javascript variable in GTM (google tag manager) to find the "trigger name" that the variable is called by and use this in a conditional statement within the variable? I can find anything online about this? Is there something way of using the API maybe. I know we can get variable names with the curly braces. Anything like this for triggers?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Usually triggers are based on built-in variables, and if you need to, you can reconstruct the trigger in your custom JS and then refer to it elsewhere.

For example, if you want to track a certain type of link click, you might start by creating the custom JS variable `isTargetLink`:

```
function() {
  var targetLinkClass = 'relevant-css-selector'
  if (targetLinkClass === {{click classes}}) {
     return true;
  }
}
```

You can then save this and refer to `isTargetLink` in another custom JS variable, e.g.

```
function() {
 if ({{isTargetLink}}) {
  // do something
 } 
}
```